# What is the next Minor release after 0.7.9?

Tags: semantic-versioning

For some, it might be easy.. But I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

So what should be the next minor release after 0.7.9?

Should it be 0.7.10? Cause I've heard from someone that 0.7.10 might be lower than 0.7.9, so I'm really unsure now.

He argumented that 0.7.91 should be the next release.

@Edit:
sorry, yes I mean next PATCH release, not minor. My fault!

Comment: I think 0.7.10 would be sufficient

Comment: I don't think 91 would be good.  9,10,11, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Google tells me that [0.7.10 is correct](https://semver.org/#spec-item-2).

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, read the [SemVer spec](https://semver.org/). In this case [#11](https://semver.org/#spec-item-11) specifies the precedence rules. In SemVer, the "triple" is treated as three unsigned integer fields, so the next patch for you would be 0.7.10.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it really comes down to how you want to document it.

v1.2.3 to me usually translates to:

> 1 would mean Major
>
> 2 would mean Minor
>
> 3 would mean Patch

Where a patch is usually a small fix, minor would be a couple new features and major would be a significant transformation in the project.

> https://semver.org/  for reference, in case you want to take a deeper look at what I mean

Comment: Thanks for the info! I corrected my question. I meant next PATCH release, not minor. Just a few bug fixes, nothing more.

Comment: I think 10 is perfectly fine :P